# Criterion of independent random vectors

Tags: probability-theory

I would like to know weather the following statements are true or false.

Given two random vectors $\boldsymbol{X} = (X_1,\cdots,X_m)$ and $\boldsymbol{Y} = (Y_1,\cdots,Y_n)$,

1. $X_i$ is independent of $Y_j$ for all $j$, then $X_i$ is independent of $\boldsymbol{Y}$.
2. if for each $i$, $X_i$ is independent of $Y_j$ for all $j$, then it implies $\boldsymbol{X}$ and $\boldsymbol{Y}$ are independent.

---

**update:**

None of the statements above seems correct.
I am looking for counterexamples.

Comment: Both wrong, as your textbook takes pains to explain.

Comment: @Did Which textbook?

Comment: Tell me. $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did Take the example from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_independence and let $\boldsymbol{X} = X$ and $\boldsymbol{Y} = (Y,Z)$?

Comment: The WP link shows both claims in your post are wrong. So, you are not using any textbook?

Comment: @Did I'm using more than one book, mainly Ash's probability and measure, Shiryayev's probability and Durrett's as well.

Comment: And Durrett does not explain that coordinate independence does not imply independence?

Comment: @Did No discussion on vector case, as far as I looked up.

Comment: Probability theory with examples, chapter 1.4.

Comment: @Did Durrett discussed independent random vector, but not independence of two random vectors.

Comment: The exercises I explicitely pointed you to, already solve your 1.